# Rabbitmq fails to start and getting Erlang eaacces error

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, erlang-otp

Describe the bug
RabbitMQ is not working after Installed Erlang OTP 24.1 and RabbitMQ Server 3.9.8

To Reproduce
User has administrator privileges
In administrator Mode install Erlang OTP 24.1 and RabbitMQ Server 3.9.8
Open Command Prompt in Admin Mode and navigate to C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.9.8\sbin
Run "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management" command

Expected behavior
RabbitMQ Management Console should be enabled

Exception Message:

```
07:46:58.176 [error] GenServer :net_kernel terminating
** (stop) {:could_not_start_server, :inet_gethost_native}
    (kernel 8.1) inet_gethost_native.erl:549: :inet_gethost_native.ensure_started/0
    (kernel 8.1) inet_gethost_native.erl:488: :inet_gethost_native.getit/2
    (kernel 8.1) inet.erl:1445: :inet.gethostbyname_tm_native/4
    (kernel 8.1) inet.erl:1396: :inet.getaddrs_tm/3
    (kernel 8.1) inet.erl:790: :inet.getaddr_tm/3
    (kernel 8.1) inet.erl:785: :inet.getaddr/3
    (kernel 8.1) inet_tcp_dist.erl:59: :inet_tcp_dist.gen_select/2
    (kernel 8.1) net_kernel.erl:1533: :net_kernel.select_mod/2
Last message: {:auto_connect, :"rabbit@EC2AMAZ-9EMRN29", {1, #Reference<0.592397178.2843344899.17153>}}
 
07:46:58.160 [error] Process #PID<0.103.0> on node :"rabbitmqcli-555-rabbit@EC2AMAZ-9EMRN29" raised an exception
** (ErlangError) Erlang error: :eacces
    erlang.erl:4430: :erlang.open_port({:spawn, 'inet_gethost 4 '}, [{:packet, 4}, :eof, :binary])
    (kernel 8.1) inet_gethost_native.erl:184: :inet_gethost_native.server_init/2
```

07:46:58.176 [error] GenServer :inet_gethost_native_sup terminating

```
(stop) :eacces
    erlang.erl:4430: :erlang.open_port({:spawn, 'inet_gethost 4 '}, [{:packet, 4}, :eof, :binary])
    (kernel 8.1) inet_gethost_native.erl:184: :inet_gethost_native.server_init/2
Last message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.103.0>, {:eacces, [{:erlang, :open_port, [{:spawn, 'inet_gethost 4 '}, [{:packet, 4}, :eof, :binary]], [file: 'erlang.erl', line: 4430, error_info: %{module: :erl_erts_errors}]}, {:inet_gethost_native, :server_init, 2, [file: 'inet_gethost_native.erl', line: 184]}]}}
escript: exception error: undefined function 'Elixir.Inspect.BitString':inspect/2
  in function  'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_each/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 402)
  in call from 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_doc/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 380)
  in call from 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_each/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 402)
  in call from 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_doc/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 380)
  in call from 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_each/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 402)
  in call from 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_doc/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 380)
  in call from 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_each/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 402)
```

Windows server 2019

It was working 10 days back and now we are seeing this issue. We tried to reinstall RMQ and erl same version but got same error.
We are expecting RabbitMQ service to start and run continuously.`